# What are the minimum requirements for Geth server only for API calls?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, php

I want to run a platform based on Ethereum and PHP to let our customers to sell/buy Ethereum based currencies online, and we have not any plan to mine the blockchain. In this regard, please help me to know what are the requirements for such server?
Also, we have chosen Geth and Parity for this purpose based on our researches. Are we right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to choose *either* Geth *or* Parity, you can't use both at the same time. But yes, one of those will work just fine for you.

As you don't need to mine you can run your client in some lighter synchronization mode. In Geth this would probably be *light* mode but depends on you. Parity has lots of similar lighter modes as well. As for the hardware requirements you'll need maybe 20GB of space (SDD) and good enough connection.

Here's more info on running a client: https://docs.ethhub.io/using-ethereum/running-an-ethereum-node/

Comment: Thank you for the provided information.